# How to split an NSString whilst retaining the separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, separator

I am using the following to separate a string by ",":

```
NSString * receivedString = @"component1,component3,,component6";
NSArray * arrayOfSubstrings = [receivedString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

However I would like to retain the "," as separate component and **obtain** the following Array:

```
[0] "component1"
[1] ","
[2] "component2"
[4] ","
[5] ","
[6] "component6"
```

**Rather** than:

```
[0] "component1"
[1] "component2"
[2] "component6"
```

Basically, a "," is an element I want to analyse as well.

Any idea on how I can do this without **re-inventing the wheel**?

Answer (score 4):

(Untested)

```
+ (NSArray *)splitString:(NSString *)string
           withSeparator:(NSString *)separator
{
    NSArray *elements = [string componentsSeparatedByString:separator];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [elements counts]; i++) {
        NSString *element = elements[i];
        if ([element length] > 0)
            [arr addObject:element];
        if (i != [elements count] - 1)
            [arr addObject:separator];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This won't catch the case where the array has two `,` in a row, as in the question.

Comment: I don't think that this will work, notice that he has two commas "," between "component 3" and "component 6". Your code will add only one comma

Comment: This does in fact work because the components ",," separated by string  "," returns an empty string.

Comment: @trojanfoe Oh, gotcha.